# How do I identify unique people under 1 id number when they are represented under different identifiers

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I am trying to ensure all customers who are the same are not being represented as multiple people by coming up with a unique identifier.
The information I am working with is transactional, so every transaction could have had different information recorded at separate times.

If Person 'A' uses email 'A' and phone 'A'

and Person 'B' uses email 'A' and phone 'B'

and Person 'C' uses email 'B' and phone 'B'

I want to deduce that Person 'A' = Person 'B' = Person 'C' even though there are variations in the identifiers.

Below is an example table

Starting Point:

| first name | last name | email | phone | street address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| j | jackson | jj@gmail | 12 | 619 Lilac |
| jon | jackson | jj@gmail | 34 |  |
| jon | jackson | jj@yahoo | 34 |  |
| Mariah | jackson | maj@gmail | 45 | 619 Lilac |
| Katy | Herring | katy@yahoo | 67 |  |
| Dalia | Smith | ds@gmail | 89 | 439 Sycamore |
| Dalia | Smith | ds@yahoo |  | 439 Sycamore |

Desired Result:

| first name | last name | email | phone | street address | unique customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| j | jackson | jj@gmail | 12 | 619 Lilac | 1 |
| jon | jackson | jj@gmail | 34 |  | 1 |
| jon | jackson | jj@yahoo | 34 |  | 1 |
| Mariah | jackson | maj@gmail | 45 | 619 Lilac | 2 |
| Katy | Herring | katy@yahoo | 67 |  | 3 |
| Dalia | Smith | ds@gmail | 89 | 439 Sycamore | 4 |
| Dalia | Smith | ds@yahoo |  | 439 Sycamore | 4 |

eventually, I want to get a place to where I am looking at household transactions, so it is okay to view parents with same name and phone number as kids (Dalia Smith/Dalia Smith jr) as the same unique customer for the time being. Also, the addresses I am working with are more specific, so I would have access to apt numbers to decipher between people with same street addresses.

Comment: hopefully none of your customer live in a large apartment building... Miss Jackson on the 1st floor may not appreciate to see the bill of Mr Jackson's that stays on the 15th floor. Dalia junior may also not appreciate being taken for her grandma Dalia senior, even if they live in an inter-generational house.

Comment: Also if someone has a son or daughter and using own email for communication this would not give desired result. (Why would a customer register twice if he's not a different person?)

Comment: You included the 'r' tag in your question so presume you are an R user? Maybe try something like the [reclin](https://github.com/djvanderlaan/reclin) package, it implements a probabilistic record linkage methodology and is quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an incredibly brute-force way to accomplish what I think you are after in R.  Basically:

1. You'll need to find every unique value of phone number, email, and address.  This can be accomplished with the `unique()` function
2. You'll need to find all rows that match each unique value of those variables. This can be accomplished with the `match()` function
3. You'll have to iteratively compare rows using conditional logic to determine whether they have matches with any other rows. There is likely a more elegant solution, but I'm not an elegant guy, so I will be using a double `for()` loop.
4. You'll have to resolve any NA values for rows that are unique

Here is an example:

```
##Fake Data##
First_Names<-c("John", "J", "John", "Maria", "Maria", "M", "Carlos", "C", "Carlos")
Last_Names<-c("Smith", "Smith", "Jones", "Valesquez", "Hidalgo", "Hidalgo","Garcia", "Garcia", "Lopez")
Email<-c("js@mail.com", "js@mail.com", "jj@mail.com", "M.V@othermail.com", "M_Hidalgo@mail.com", "M.Hidalgo@mail.com", "C_G@othermail.com", "C_G@othermail.com", "Lopez.Carlos@mail.com")
Phone<-c("555-1111", "666-1111", "555-2222", "555-3333", "555-4444", "555-4444", "555-5555", "555-5555", "555-6666")
Address<-c("1 A st", "1 A st", "2 B st", "3 C st", "4 D st", "4 D st", "5 E st", "5 E st", "6 F st")

DF<-data.frame(First_Names=First_Names, Last_Names=Last_Names, Email=Email, Phone=Phone, Address=Address)

#List of all possible Emails, Phones, and Addresses
email<-unique(DF$Email)
phone<-unique(DF$Phone)
address<-unique(DF$Address)

#finding matching values#
email_match<-match(DF$Email,email)
phone_match<-match(DF$Phone,phone)
address_match<-match(DF$Address,address)
DF$email_match<-email_match
DF$phone_match<-phone_match
DF$address_match<-address_match

#Create a blank field for Unique ID
DF[,"UID"]<-NA

#Nasty Double, nested for loop to compare all three match variables
for(i in 1:(nrow(DF)-1)){
  if(i==1){
    DF$UID[i]<-1
  }
    
  for(j in 2:nrow(DF)){
    if(!is.na(DF$UID[j])){
     DF$UID[j]<-DF$UID[j]
    }else{
      if(DF$email_match[i]==DF$email_match[j]|
        DF$phone_match[i]==DF$phone_match[j]|
         DF$address_match[i]==DF$address_match[j]
         ){
        DF$UID[j]<-i
      }
      
      }
    }
}

##Find any non-matching values##

for(i in 1:length(DF$UID)){
  tmp<-0
  if(is.na(DF$UID[i])){
    tmp<-tmp+1
    DF$UID[i]<-max(DF$UID[-which(is.na(DF$UID))])+1
  }
}

print(DF)
```